# Запуск nose test с пользовательским аргументом

Tags: python, python-2.x, тестирование

Есть nose тест, который я запускаю как

```
nosetests --tests=my_file -p1 some_arg1 -p2 some_arg2
```

Вот сам тест:

```
import argparse
import nose
from nose.tools import istest


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Arguments for running test')
    parser.add_argument('-p1', '--path1', type=str, help='Some help text', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-p2', '--path2', type=str, help='Some help text', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    path1 = args.path1
    path2 = args.path2
    return [path1, path2]
nose.run()


@istest
def my_test(my_path1=get_args()[0], my_path2=get_args()[1]):
    print my_path1, my_path2
    pass
```

Мне nose на это выдаёт  `nosetests: error: no such option: -1`

Кроме того пробовал запускать nose так:

```
python my_file.py --tests=my_file.py -p1 some_arg1 -p2 some_arg2
```

Вопрос: как запустить nose тест с пользовательским аргументом?

Comment: 1- Не ясно что вы хотите сделать. Вы должны выбрать что-то одно: либо ваш скрипт запускайте, либо вы `nosetests` команду запускаете (и передаёте те аргументы, которая она ожидает. Обратите внимание, nosetests пытается *импортировать* ваш модуль и вызывать функции в нём -- это отличается от запуска Питон-модуля как скрипта). 2- `nose.run()` вы вероятно хотите убрать в `if __name__=="__main__"` ветку. `get_args()` у вас в момент определения функции вызывается. Если вы вызываете `nose.run()`, то аргументы командной строки обрабатываются nose. Словами опишите, что у вас есть и что хотите получить.

Comment: @jfs 1 Это я знаю, к сожалению. 2 Я хочу запустить набор тестов и в качестве аргумента передать какой-то свой ключ или несколько своих ключей.

Comment: Если вы какие то свои действия хотите выполнить, то 1- запускайте свой скрипт, а не nosetests 2- после обработки, удалите свои аргументы из sys.argv,перед тем как управление в nose передать (если вы хотите гибридные аргументы передавать) перед вызовом nose.run() или nose.main() 3- во время импорта этот код не должен выполняться (спрячьте в `if __name__ == '__main__': main()`)